# .NET developer has a few hours to cram for a Java proficiency test. What to do?

Tags: java, .net, testing

I have an interview tomorrow morning and just found out that I will also be taking an hour-long Java proficiency test!

I am a certified C# .NET developer but have barely touched Java since college. (Yes, I am thinking about switching from .NET development to Java!)

I'm not going to be able to effectively cram the whole of the Java library by tomorrow morning. What are some key ideas that I should study that might actually make a difference in such a short time frame? (The examiners will be taking into account that I have had little exposure to Java.)

Thanks!

**Edit NOTE:** I think that the exam is going to be written, so no specific IDE.

Comment: Just lower case the method names from .NET and you'll be fine.

Comment: Do you know what type of applications they want you to work on?

Comment: @Chris: The apps are going to be a mix of some web front end but mostly server-side stuff.

Comment: What is the reason for switching to Java, if I may ask?

Comment: @kahoon: I am contracting on a short-term .NET project for a great company that is mostly a Java shop. The stint was supposed to be a short contract but may turn from temp to perm. Looking for a way to stay with a great and stable company. A new challenge would also be nice.

Comment: @Paul Sasik: That's reasonable, I think. How did the interview go anyway?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631390?tab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have time enough to take a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C_Sharp). You probably won't need to read all of it, just the key points.

I would emphasize some differences:

- Java cannot overload operators
- Java has nothing like Linq as far as I'm concerned
- Java has no delegates
- If you're going to develop GUI oriented software, you're entering a whole new world
- Java package structure is different from the namespace structure, although a little bit similar
- In Java you always have to catch exceptions. You cannot just ignore them
- Java does not have `ref` and `out` parameters
- Java does not have the `using` keyword
- In Java syntax you have to explicitly define getters and setters
  For example:

  public int getX() { return x; }
  public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
- Java has no `goto`

Comment: That wiki article is great. JVM via .NET? ;-) (Referring to CLR via C#)

Comment: Paul, I could not find this part. Where is it? :/

Comment: Sorry Paulo. I was joking... There is a well-respected .NET book called CLR via C#. I thought mentioning JVM via .NET might entertain some people. Sorry for the confusion. And i meant that as an alternate title to the article.

Comment: Oh, no problem. It's because I do not know this book. :-)

Comment: no goto, but it has got labeled blocks, so you can break and continue to those labeled blocks.

Answer (score 1):

IDK about you but I never try to fluff my skills.  You know what you know and you don't know much about Java.  As you said, they should know this and should take this into account.

I personally try to find a job that fits my skills so I can continue to grow them. If you always try to sway your skills to a job listing that you've found, well, you'll be doing that for the rest of your life!

As for java stuff, C# very similar as you know, just remember you cant do

```
string a = "aa";
string b = "cc";

if (a == b)
{}
```

you have to do something like

```
if (b.isEqualTo(a))
{}
```

or someting like that (cant remember)

Comment: i completely agree about the fluffing. i don't want to "trick" anyone and set myself up for inflated expectations. Just looking to a little warm up, especially in a way where I can examine Java from the .NET perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I supose that could be helpful: [Tech Interviews - Java](http://www.techinterviews.com/interview-questions/java) 
It's a really nice collection of java connected job interviews questions with answers divided into different categories. You can check your situation quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Do you get to use an IDE? If yes, I think you should look at lots of libraries to learn the syntax.

If there is no IDE, then <strike>you are screwed</strike> buy [Head First Java](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009205) (available in PDF).

Comment: Head First Java's on my shopping list but it won't help for an overnight cram. Maybe if i had a weekend...

Answer (score 0):

If the examiners are taking into account the fact that you have had little exposure to Java recently, you should be fine.

Since Java and C# are so closely related, you will do just fine.

Maybe brush up on some Java basics like the API docs and the Sun/Oracle tutorials for anything specific.

Most importantly, though, is to make sure you use correct syntax. Java and C# are similar, but obviously not the same.

Also be familiar with whatever (if any) IDE you will be using. It can help you **immensely** when you write your code.

Comment: check the reserved words, that should give you a good grasp of the differences

Answer (score 0):

Good luck.! :)
May be the test doesn't matter, they should understand how good a .NET dev you are and Java is just a medium.